# PyQt5 Button unexpected type 'str'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm working on a Password Generator using PyQt5.

What I want it to do is when you press the button, it generates the password on the text box (where it says "Your Password Here").

[image]

When I run the app, it throws a TypeError.

Here is the code:

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw
import PyQt5.QtGui as qtg
import random

chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}|\;:',<.>/?`~"


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    def generate_password():
        pwd = ""
        password_len = my_spin.value()
        for x in range(0,password_len):
            password_char = random.choice(chars)
            pwd = pwd + password_char
        return pwd
        my_pwd.setText(pwd)


    # Title
    self.setWindowTitle("Random Password Generator")

    # Layout
    self.setLayout(qtw.QVBoxLayout())

    # Label
    my_label = qtw.QLabel("Set the Password Length")
    # Set Font Size of the Label
    my_label.setFont(qtg.QFont('Courier New', 12))
    self.layout().addWidget(my_label)
    # Spin Box
    my_spin = qtw.QSpinBox(self, value=12, maximum=32, minimum=6, singleStep=12)
    self.layout().addWidget(my_spin)
    # Password Box Label
    pwd_label = qtw.QLabel("Your Secure Password")
    pwd_label.setFont(qtg.QFont('Courier New', 12))
    self.layout().addWidget(pwd_label)
    # Entry Box
    my_pwd = qtw.QLineEdit()
    my_pwd.setObjectName("Password")
    my_pwd.setText("Your Password Here")
    self.layout().addWidget(my_pwd)
    # Button
    my_button = qtw.QPushButton("Generate New Password", clicked=generate_password())
    self.layout().addWidget(my_button)

    self.show()

app = qtw.QApplication([])
mw = MainWindow()


app.exec_()
```

And when I launch main.py this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mtthw\PycharmProjects\RandomPasswordGenerator\main.py", line 53, in <module>
    mw = MainWindow()
  File "C:\Users\mtthw\PycharmProjects\RandomPasswordGenerator\main.py", line 46, in __init__
    my_button = qtw.QPushButton("Generate New Password", clicked=generate_password())
TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

I'm not able to tell why it's not able to accept a string, which is what I want the app to output on the text box, a string of random characters. Is there a certain way to set up the PyQt5 button to invoke a function when it's clicked?

Comment: You actually called the `generate_password()` function yourself, during the creation of the button, and are trying to pass its return value (a string) as the `clicked=` parameter.  You want to pass an actual function (so that the button can call it when clicked), so get rid of those parentheses.

Comment: That helped, I guess the argument is being read as a string when I add the parentheses.

When I removed them, the GUI launched without errors, but the button didn't work.

Comment: Qt uses signals and slots to set up connections between widgets; you don't pass a callback to the widget's constructor like you do with Tk.

Comment: @Samwise TYPO(s): 1. remove the parentheses as explained above; 2. remove the `return pwd` (or at least move it a line below) as it prevents calling `my_pwd.setText(pwd)`: ***anything*** after a `return` *statement* is ignored, even if the syntax is conceptually correct (except for what happens in the `finally:` in a `try:` block, which is ***always*** guaranteed to be executed and could even override any of the previous `return` statements).

Comment: This was very helpful, and it got the button to work as intended. Thank you so much for your help.

I added the `return pwd` line because I didn't think the function would have returned any value into the text box, but it turns out it's not even needed.

Thank you, I've learned a lot from this

Answer (score 1):

```
my_button = qtw.QPushButton("Generate New Password", clicked=generate_password())
```

`QPushButton()` doesn't accept a `clicked` parameter; it's probably throwing that error because the extra argument makes it think you're trying to construct a button with `"Generate New Password"` as an icon.  What you want to do is:

```
my_button = qtw.QPushButton("Generate New Password")
my_button.clicked.connect(generate_password)
```

Note that you should put the `@Slot` decorator on your `generate_password` function definition (which makes it a slot that is a valid target for a `connect()` call).

See the basic button tutorial on the Qt website: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/tutorials/basictutorial/clickablebutton.html

Comment: Okay, I put a decorator on the generate password function definition, I was able to launch the GUI with no errors, but the button still doesn't do anything.

Also I realized I didn't install and import the PySide2 module to use the `@Slot()` decorator,, so I did that as well, but the button still doesn't work as intended.

Comment: @Samwise Many things you're saying here are wrong. First of all, the issue is *calling* the function instead of passing the reference. Then, PyQt *does* support using signals as keyword arguments by providing the relative slot (see the [documentation](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#connecting-signals-using-keyword-arguments). Finally, not only the `Slot` decorator (which is `pyqtSlot` in PyQt, by the way) is not mandatory for general cases, but it also doesn't work for generic functions, since slots are only available for *methods* of QObject subclasses.

Comment: sounds like a good bug to file against the Qt doc!

Comment: There's no Qt bug here. Just remove `return pwd`.

Answer (score 0):

@samwise is right.

Your code had other bugs. I tried to fix them.

```
from string import printable
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw
import PyQt5.QtGui as qtg
import random

class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Title
        self.setWindowTitle("Random Password Generator")

        # Layout
        self.setLayout(qtw.QVBoxLayout())

        # Label
        self.my_label = qtw.QLabel("Set the Password Length")
        self.my_label.setFont(qtg.QFont('Courier New', 12))
        self.layout().addWidget(self.my_label)
        
        # Spin Box
        self.my_spin = qtw.QSpinBox(self, value=12, maximum=32, minimum=6, singleStep=12)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.my_spin)
        
        # Password Box Label
        self.pwd_label = qtw.QLabel("Your Secure Password")
        self.pwd_label.setFont(qtg.QFont('Courier New', 12))
        self.layout().addWidget(self.pwd_label)
        
        # Entry Box
        self.my_pwd = qtw.QLineEdit()
        self.my_pwd.setObjectName("Password")
        self.my_pwd.setText("Your Password Here")
        self.layout().addWidget(self.my_pwd)
        
        # Button
        self.my_button = qtw.QPushButton("Generate New Password")
        self.my_button.clicked.connect(self.generate_password)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.my_button)

        self.show()
        
    def generate_password(self):
        self.my_pwd.setText(
            "".join(
                random.choice(printable)
                for _ in range(self.my_spin.value())
            )
        )
        
app = qtw.QApplication([])
mw = MainWindow()

app.exec_()
```